# Forward a subdomain to another server/domain's subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain

I have two domains on two different servers, both with the same subdomain: 
**subd.domain1.com (Linux Server)

subd.domain2.com (ASP .NET Server)** This is why I'm doing this

---

What I need to do is have `subd.domain1.com` be populated by the content at `subd.domain2.com`.

In other words, I'd like to mask `subd.domain2.com` with `subd.domain1.com`.

I tried a simple A-name with the IP of `domain2.com` (just a random shot before searching, thought there could be some hidden functionality for this in DNS settings). Also I messed around with 301 Redirects using `mod_rewrite`. I really don't know what the best way to do this would be (if I can), and my searches honestly aren't helping.

Comment: Please clarify, your question is too vague.

Comment: When someone goes to `subd.domain1.com` I'd like it to go to `subd.domain1.com`, but it's content be populated by `subs.domain2.com` (or just `domain2.com` I guess)

Comment: iframe?? check this out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Comment: Well yeah, that should be fine. Add an answer and I'll accept it, if you like. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames allow a visual HTML Browser window to be split into segments, each of which can show a different document. [More Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames)

In the context of a web browser, a frame is a part of a web page or browser window which displays content independent of its container, with the ability to load content independently. The HTML or media elements that go in a frame may or may not come from the same web site as the other elements of content on display.[More Info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framing_%28World_Wide_Web%29)

[W3C iframe Info](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5)

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Iframe ! Content that is in an iframe is NOT indexed as part of the url by the search engines -- because the iframe content is at another url.

You can use simple php file to make it, (if your target page .php file):

```
<?PHP include('http://www.url/to/file');?>
```

And if the page .htm you can add this line to .htaccess:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

then you can include .htm as .php .